# jQuery hide and show functions are not working with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

Want to display loader when ajax call is processing. But hide and show doesn't work in runtime. In debug mode it's ok. I've tried to put timeout on ajax, but no result.

```
function Rate() {
    $("#rate_navigation").hide();
    $("#rate_loader").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data: "data",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#comment_result").html(msg.d);
        },
        error: AjaxCallError
    });

    $("#rate_loader").hide();
    $("#rate_navigation").show();
}
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous!

Comment: You should put last 2 lines in the success function

Comment: So it doesn't hide? Doesn't show? Both? what exactly do you want to happen and when?

Comment: @Barmar but SJAX isn't `async: false,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beforeSend` and `complete`.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function Rate() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data: "data",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#rate_navigation").hide();
            $("#rate_loader").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#rate_loader").hide();
            $("#rate_navigation").show();
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#comment_result").html(msg.d);
        },
        error: AjaxCallError
    });
}
```

Comment: very good answer. Thanks. I've put async: true to make loader more effective.

Answer (score 1):

Throw these into your success callback:

```
success: function (msg) {
        $("#rate_loader").hide();
        $("#rate_navigation").show();
        $("#comment_result").html(msg.d);
    },
    error: AjaxCallError
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put the unhide condition inside success

```
function Rate() {
$("#rate_navigation").hide();
$("#rate_loader").show();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: "data",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#comment_result").html(msg.d);


        $("#rate_loader").hide();
        $("#rate_navigation").show();
    },
    error: AjaxCallError
});


}
```